# Adobe Flash disabled in Chromium after update. How to fix this?

Tags: flash, chromium

Flash was working fine in Chromium. Then I got a notification there was an update for Chromium. After upgrading Flash stops working in Chromium. It seems for some reason it was disabled:

> chrome://version/

shows:

> Chromium  30.0.1599.114 (Developer Build
>   30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)
>
> Ubuntu 13.04 OS   Linux
>
> Blink 537.36 (@159105)
>
> JavaScript    V8 3.20.17.15
>
> Flash (Disabled)

Flash still works in Firefox so this is a problem of Chromium. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Open terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
chromium-browser --enable-plugins
```

If that works, then go to Applications -->Internet -->Chromium Browser and right click it, add to panel.Right click the new chromium icon and add the following command where it says command

```
chromium-browser --enable-plugins
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. "chromium-browser --enable-plugins" opened a new chromium window that still has Flash shown as "Disabled".